# jquery watermark not working after form.reset

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, reset

I have `jQuery WaterMark` on `Textbox` field. [**Link**](http://digitalbush.com/projects/watermark-input-plugin/)

When user click on `Refresh button` i am trying to ***reset the form with clearing textbox from codebehind. It clear perfectly but it also don't show the `WaterMark`***

May be it is that watermark works on `OnBlur` event and it is not firing.

Using that in the head tag (Note: nothing in the asp textbox)

```
<script src="../../jquery/watermark/jquery.watermarkinput.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function ($) {
        $("#txtAccounts").Watermark("Type something to search Accounts", "gray");
    });
</script>
```

**Edit:**

***`It is also not working after any post event`***

Answer (score 1):

According the website you've provided, are you using the `$.Watermark.ShowAll();` after the reset of your form?

**Update**

If you are able to move the reset to the clienside, you can use the `ShowAll();` like this:

```
<script src="../../jquery/watermark/jquery.watermarkinput.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function ($) {
        $("#txtAccounts").Watermark("Type something to search Accounts", "gray");
    });

    $("#TheIdOfYourButton").click(function(){
        $("#TheIdOfYourForm")[0].reset();
        $.Watermark.ShowAll();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Posted the code. Nope i am not using showAll at all. How can i?

Comment: Is it possible to move the reset to the Clientside (i.e. javascript)? In that case you can reset the form by a click on a button and after that show the watermarks again.

Comment: yep i can use the client-side reset() but it isn't working for me. Doesn't resets the fields.

Comment: Can you also provide the html of the form (rendered version)? Makes it a bit easier for me to create the correct script you need :)